# How to make a widget invisible in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to show and hide `ProgressIndicator` in a column.
the problem is when I want to hide the `ProgressIndicator`, the space between other widgets will be removed too (like `View.GONE`) but I want to keep widget size (like `View.INVISIBLE`)

example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Main(isLoading: Boolean) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "Text")

        if (isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }

        Button(onClick = { /*clicked*/ }, content = { Text(text = "Button") })    
    }
}
```

I found a solution but I'm not sure if it's the right way.

```kotlin
if (isLoading) {
    CircularProgressIndicator()
} else {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))
}
```

Is there any other way for making the widget invisible like `View.INVISIBLE`?

How can I get widget size to set `Spacer` size?

Thanks

Comment: You could try [an alpha of 0](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).alpha(kotlin.Float))

Comment: @CommonsWare It's perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 30):

Use Alpha **Zero** , this is mentioned in the comments by @commonsware, as you do not need to know the size about the space size, unlike to Spacer() composable which needs a specific size and in some cases this may be hard to know.

```
val commentsAlpha = if (condition) 1f else 0f
modifier = Modifier
            .alpha(commentsAlpha)
```

Comment: I tried this one:  0f working, it will be invisible, but the widget has empty space

Comment: @HariShankarS That's the expected behavior for invisible. If you want it removed it would be "gone".

Comment: Please note that any Button or similar will stay clickable even if invisible!

Comment: @m.reiter thanks for mentioning it

Comment: @m.reiter so for a button you can use `onClick = { if (condition) onClick() }` to fix that.

Comment: @MarioHuizinga`.clickable(enabled = condition){ onClick() }` is readily available

Answer (score 6):

You can use a custom layout modifier, that defines an empty area of the composable you want to make invisible. It also prevents receiving any touch events when invisible.

```
fun Modifier.visibility(visible: Boolean): Modifier {
    return layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            if (visible) {
                // place this item in the original position
                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when used with an Icon(). It's not being recomposed properly for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the following method: **AnimatedVisibility**
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedvisibility

```
 // Create a MutableTransitionState<Boolean> for the AnimatedVisibility.
                val state = remember {
                    MutableTransitionState(false).apply {
                        // Start the animation immediately.
                        targetState = true
                    }
                }
                Column {
                    AnimatedVisibility(visibleState = state) {
                        Text(text = "Hello, world!")
                    }

                    // Use the MutableTransitionState to know the current animation state
                    // of the AnimatedVisibility.
                    Text(
                        text = when {
                            state.isIdle && state.currentState -> "Visible"
                            !state.isIdle && state.currentState -> "Disappearing"
                            state.isIdle && !state.currentState -> "Invisible"
                            else -> "Appearing"
                        }
                    )
                }
```

[image]

It is also useful for observing the animation state.

Comment: This won't make the content invisible, it rather removes it (like GONE).

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct, but you could also wrap your progress indicator in a Box of the expected size

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp) {
    if (condition) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this solution is good but I have to set `Modifier.height()` manually.

Comment: Also is important to say that doing this will always recreate the composable. Then if inside it had some side effects (for example) all those effects will be recreated. Be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if (isLoading) {
    CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
} else {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.